# Brand new bass, annoying fret buzz

Tags: bass-guitar

I know this question has come up multiple times here on this website, but I think that it's kind of strange to have fret buzz with a brand new bass. This happens most on the two middle strings, and I can only avoid the buzz by pressing the strings really hard, which makes it really hard to play fast. Maybe it's my technique that is wrong, because I don't think that a brand new bass wasn't calibrated.

Any opinions on this? is my technique or is the bass that is not calibrated?

Ps: this is the one http://www.thomann.de/pt/harley_benton_mb222t.htm

Comment: Can you take it back and exchange it for one that doesn't have buzz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could very well be set up quickly and to the manufacturer's specs which don't work for your type of playing, or was done in a rush to begin with.  This happens often, and adjustment (assuming you have a set of hex keys) is pretty easy.

The clue I'm going with is:

> ...This happens most on the two middle strings...

This really isn't that big of a deal.  If you're not encountering this on the outer strings then your neck is set well, and relief is good.  However, your inner two strings probably sit considerably (enough) closer to the fretboard causing the buzz.  **The easy fix for this is an adjustment at the bridge to raise (you don't need much) the height of the string to match more of the fretboard radius**.  [Check out this video for adjustment](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQrdSji6LKAhUDMSYKHfZ9CKwQtwIIHDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D26-n2rGnKAg&usg=AFQjCNF4wDXNuuX5dj2kIQZ7tcfN-MYTNQ&sig2=EEfMPqF2QB_YAGGYHisRwA&bvm=bv.111396085,d.eWE).

---

If above doesn't solve the problem then I'm afraid you may just not be pressing hard enough (I can't judge your experience with bass right now).  I only get the feeling of this by the following statement:

> ...and I can only avoid the buzz by pressing the strings really hard...

To get a clear, loud note out of a fretted one, you may need to press a bit harder than you think (especially if you're starting out, and not used to the amount of pressure required by a bass).

If this is the case, you may want to look more into proper positioning of your thumb on the back of the neck to provide the right anchor point and applied pressure you're looking for.

**EDIT:** Considering it's a Harley Benton, the setup process was probably just not done properly, and a quick neck/bridge setup may all be all that's necessary.  [Make sure this bass also has a straight neck](http://www.guitarworld.com/eds-shed-how-tell-if-your-guitar-s-neck-needs-be-adjusted) (Excuse Guitar World's ads).

Comment: If the problem goes away when pressing down the strings sufficiently hard, then it may in fact help to _lower_ the action, so it's easier to do that. It is indeed more typical that buzz is caused by _too low_ action, but in that case the buzz doesn't care how hard you press down on the strings, so if pressure helps then the issue is probably not that the action is too low.

Comment: I don't know, if I had a brand new bass with fret buzz when I'm not playing that hard, I'd take it back either way. If the neck or frets are fine, then the store should have done a decent setup and I want a free setup. The last time I bought a guitar new from a store (as opposed to used or online), they pretty much insisted that they do a setup on it before handing it to me, probably to make sure I didn't want to take it back right after getting it home.

Comment: Oh the days of customer service!  Half the guitars at Guitar Center are unplayable!

Comment: I think the top half is the answer. If the neck cross section has a radius (is curved), but the bridge saddles are dead flat, then yeah, the middle two strings are closer to the fretboard. Raise them to mimic the radius, it won't take much.